# Deserialize only certain tagged fields with DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, attributes, datacontractserializer

I have a class with some fields and properties:

```
[DataContract]
public class Order {
    [DataMember]
    [FromTemplate]
    public string orderNo;

    [DataMember]
    public List<Element> elements;
}
```

I created an Attribute that I use to tag certain fields:

```
public class FromTemplate : System.Attribute
{
    public FromTemplate() { }
}
```

Now I have this special case when want to deserialize a template XML file with default values into the objects that are tagged with `[FromTemplate]`.

This is my deserialization code:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static T deserializeFromTemplate<T>(this T obj, string filename)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(fs, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()))
            {
                var x = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                obj = (T) x.ReadObject(reader);
                reader.Close();
                fs.Close();
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }

    public static Main() {
        Order order;
        order = order.deserializeFromTemplate("template.xml");
    }
}
```

But this obviously deserializes all `[DataMember]` objects. How can I filter out only the `[FromTemplate]` objects?